# Android SQLite structure

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Quick question. Is there a way to create a SQL table in in android so that it would follow this format?

```
[Users Name]
|
Date
  |
  Points
```

but be able to have multiple dates under one user like:

```
[Users Name]
|
Date
  |
  Points
|
Date
  |
  Points
```

and be able to enumerate the dates and their respected points?
So far I have been able to create an SQL table and add things to it but I haven't seen anything like this.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Sure: UserName, Date, Points. Just add a record for each date/points with the same user name and then filter by UserName when retrieving data. It's not a structure, just a plain tabular (matrix) format. Which is enough.

Comment: how is this related to android?

Comment: Nor to SQLite, specifically.

Comment: It's going to be part of the app that I am slowly making. So I thought that it related. If someone wants to change the the post they can.

Comment: No there is now way to *economically* do this with one table.  You need on a sqlite android db two tables, a foreign key, and a view.

Comment: @danny117 I'll take a look at you code tomorrow but or now I have to go to work. Looks promising though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two tables one with users one with date-points.  date-points would have a foreign key to users.

I have a similar structure in my GPS logging application.  Two tables one with locations and one with markers.  I can have multiple markers at any given location.  It also has a foreign key and a view so I can easily look at the data.

```
// version 47
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_ACCURACY = "accuracy";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_ALTITUDE = "altitude";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_BEARING = "bearing";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_PROVIDER = "provider";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_SPEED = "speed";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION_TIME = "timemillis";
public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";

private static final String VERSION_47_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_LOCATION_ACCURACY + " REAL," + KEY_LOCATION_ALTITUDE
        + " REAL," + KEY_LOCATION_BEARING + " REAL,"
        + KEY_LOCATION_LATITUDE + " REAL," + KEY_LOCATION_LONGITUDE
        + " REAL," + KEY_LOCATION_PROVIDER + " TEXT," + KEY_LOCATION_SPEED
        + " REAL," + KEY_LOCATION_TIME + " INTEGER" + ")";

// version 56
public static final String TABLE_MARKERS = "markers";

public static final String KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID = "markerlocationid";
public static final String KEY_MARKER_SNIPPET = "markersnippet";
public static final String KEY_MARKER_TITLE = "markertitle";
public static final String KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID = "imageid";

public static final String VIEW_MARKERS = "viewMarkers";

private static final String VERSION_57_DROP_VIEW = "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " + VIEW_MARKERS;
private static final String VERSION_57_DROP_IDX = "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS IDX_MARKERS_UPDATE";
private static final String VERSION_57_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
        + TABLE_MARKERS;
private static final String VERSION_57_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_MARKERS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID
        + " INTEGER," + KEY_MARKER_SNIPPET + " TEXT," + KEY_MARKER_TITLE
        + " TEXT," + " FOREIGN KEY(" + KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID
        + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + KEY_ID + "),"
        + " CONSTRAINT UNQ_" + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID + " UNIQUE ("
        + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID + ") ON CONFLICT ABORT)";

private static final String VERSION_57_CREATE_INDEX = "CREATE INDEX IDX_MARKERS_UPDATE ON "
        + TABLE_MARKERS + "(" + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID + ")";

private static final String VERSION_57_CREATE_VIEW = "CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "
        + VIEW_MARKERS
        + " AS SELECT "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + "."
        + KEY_ID
        + ", "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + "."
        + KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID
        + ", "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + "."
        + KEY_MARKER_IMAGE_ID
        + ", "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + "."
        + KEY_MARKER_SNIPPET
        + ", "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + "."
        + KEY_MARKER_TITLE
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_LATITUDE
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_LONGITUDE
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_ACCURACY
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_ALTITUDE
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_BEARING
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_PROVIDER
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_SPEED
        + ", "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + "."
        + KEY_LOCATION_TIME
        + " FROM "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + " JOIN "
        + TABLE_LOCATIONS
        + " ON "
        + TABLE_MARKERS
        + "."
        + KEY_MARKER_LOCATION_ID + " = " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "." + KEY_ID;



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
    while (upgradeTo <= newVersion) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int res;
        switch (upgradeTo) {
```

...

```
        case 47:
            // new table for locations
            db.execSQL(VERSION_47_CREATE_TABLE);
            break;

        case 48:
            // new Route Recorder Map
            KmlSummary kmx = new KmlSummary(this.context);
            // save with constant
            kmx.set_bounds(-32.00003744494595, -139.36084538698196,
                    77.75562121925783, -26.860628958451784);
            kmx.set_resrawid(Main.SAMPLE_LOCATION_RECORDER);
            kmx.set_description("This map shows the Best Rides route recorder map");
            kmx.set_name("Best Rides Route Recorder Map");
            addRide(kmx, db);
            break;
        // version 50 has new table markers with foreign indx on locations
        case 57:
            db.execSQL(VERSION_57_DROP_VIEW);
            db.execSQL(VERSION_57_DROP_IDX);
            db.execSQL(VERSION_57_DROP);
            db.execSQL(VERSION_57_CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(VERSION_57_CREATE_INDEX);
            db.execSQL(VERSION_57_CREATE_VIEW);
            break;
        }
        upgradeTo++;
    }
}
```